# using msbuild within PowerShell to edit a csproj on the install event in NuGet

Tags: xml, powershell, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package

I saw a great example for what I'm trying to do on [Daniel Cazzulino's Blog](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/how-to-add-an-msbuild-import-to-a-project-on-nuget-install/) at Clarius. I’d like to do something similar to what he did.

I am trying to deliver some basic **T4 templates** via **NuGet** and have a problem because each of them have an entry in the **csproj** file that says `<Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>` which makes them all run independently which is not desireable. If the value read like this `<Generator></Generator>`, then everything would be ok.

I would like to remove this setting using the **msbuild** like you modified the **csproj** in the example above. 
I have written a **PowerShell** script to remove the offending value, but it requires unloading the project. **Msbuild** seems better suited for this task, but I’m unfamiliar with it. I’ve done some searching, but am still in the dark.

The difference between what he did and what I want to do is that he added something and I want to edit something, but I don't know how to locate the info using the **msbuild** xml traversing methods.

Here’s the **PowerShell** script that I wrote with @Keith Hill's help:

```
$ns = @{msb = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'}
$results = 0
$xml = [xml](gc $projName)
$xml | Select-Xml "//msb:Generator" -Namespace $ns | 
       Foreach { 
           $_.Node.set_InnerText('')
           $results = 1
       }
if($results -eq 1){
    $xml.Save($project.FullName)
}
```

Any suggestions on how to do this in msbuild?

Here's Daniel's code (it exists within the Install.ps1 file that is a part of the NuGet install life-cycle):

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)
    # This is the MSBuild targets file to add
    $targetsFile = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($toolsPath, 'Funq.Build.targets')

    # Need to load MSBuild assembly if it's not loaded yet.
    Add-Type -AssemblyName 'Microsoft.Build, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
    # Grab the loaded MSBuild project for the project
    $msbuild = [Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection]::GlobalProjectCollection.GetLoadedProjects($project.FullName) | Select-Object -First 1

    # Make the path to the targets file relative.
    $projectUri = new-object Uri('file://' + $project.FullName)
    $targetUri = new-object Uri('file://' + $targetsFile)
    $relativePath = $projectUri.MakeRelativeUri($targetUri).ToString().Replace([System.IO.Path]::AltDirectorySeparatorChar, [System.IO.Path]::DirectorySeparatorChar)

    # Add the import and save the project
    $msbuild.Xml.AddImport($relativePath) | out-null
    $project.Save()
```

Comment: I gave up on it because it was too difficult for the payoff. No answer is marked because I naver got an opportunity to try Filburt's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using the [XmlPoke Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff598687.aspx):

```
<Project DefaultTargets="PokeGenerator">
    <ItemGroup>
        <MyProjectFile Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\MyProject.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="PokeGenerator">
        <XmlPoke XmlInputPath="%(ProjectConfigFile.FullPath)"
            Query="/x:Project/x:ItemGroup/x:Compile/x:Generator"
            Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='x' Uri='http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' /&gt;"
            Value="%0a" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

You just need to modify the `XmlInputPath` and `Query` parameters to fit to your needs.

The gotchas are that you have to declare a namespace prefix even if the project file doesn't use any namespace prefix and that you need to provide a value to poke into the selected element - I figured a newline won't hurt.